# Make the active console darker

Tags: conemu

Conemu makes the active console lighter than the inactive one, effectively lowering the contrast and making it harder to read text. I can't find the option to stop it from doing this. Is it possible to stop this?

I'm on Win 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. ConEmu makes **inactive** console darker.

And yes, you may disable the feature by [Fade when inactive](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsColors.html) checkbox.

Comment: I want to make the active window lighter (inactive window doesn't bother me). If I open git bash, and git bash in ConEmu with the same monitor settings, git bash is significantly darker (thus, better contrast). This actually made me thing ConEmu makes it lighter. Is there a way to make things darker?

Comment: Ok, it was a palette issue. Using the xterm palette solves the contrast issue.